# How to get the text of dynamically added li of ul in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a variable which may contain multiple comma separated values. I wanted to split and dynamically display in lis in an unordered list.

When each li is clicked, I need to grab the text inside the li to use in a later function. I've tried to do this below unsuccessfully.

Please help me to get the text of each li when it is clicked.

```
 function viewUploadedFiles() {
 var fpath = $("#filePathList").val();
 var fnameVal = $("#fileNameList").val();
 var display = displayFiles(fnameVal);
 $("#upload_FileList").html(display);
}

function displayFiles(fname) {
  var septor = ',';
  var selected="<ul class='file_List' >";
     if (fname.indexOf(septor) >= 0) {
         var fnameArray = fname.split(septor);
         $.each(fnameArray, function(index,value) {
             alert(index+" Files ===> "+value);
                selected+='<li class="file_list_line" id="file_ID"><span class="text">'+value+'</span><input type="button" value="Delete File" onclick="deleteFile()"></li>';
         });

     } else {
         selected+='<li class="file_list_line" id="file_ID"><span class="text">'+fname+'</span><input type="button" value="Delete File" onclick="deleteFile()"></li>';
     }
     selected+='</ul>';
    return selected;
}

function deleteFile(){
alert($(this).text());
}

<div id="upload_FileList" align="left">
</div>
```

Comment: can you put up a JSfuddle so we have a working example of what you are trying to achieve and where it's failing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/login2app/J5nCS/506/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small change to the script you used to get it to work on jsfiddle. The issue you were running into was that the deleteFile() function is not available when the button is clicked. Removing the inline function call and registering the call using delegation with jquery fixes your problem.

Assuming you put the generated html markup inside the list, you need to add this to your script.

```
$('#upload_FileList').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    console.log($(this).text())
});
```

This simply triggers the function whenever an LI inside the `upload_filelist` UL is clicked.

Here's the functioning fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/t99sm54q/1/